# $\aleph_1$-categorical fields are algebraically closed.

Tags: reference-request, model-theory

I'd like to understand the proof that if $K$ is an infinite field the theory of $K$ is  $\aleph_1$-categorical, then $K$ is algebraically closed--but I'm having trouble finding it in the literature. Any ideas where I can find the appropriate paper(s)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is called Macintyre's Theorem. In fact, the following are equivalent for infinite fields:

1. $K$ is algebraically closed
2. $\text{Th}(K)$ is $\aleph_1$-categorical
3. $K$ is totally transcendental
4. $\text{Th}(K)$ has quantifier elimination

The original paper is:

Macintyre, Angus, *[On $\omega_1$-categorical theories of fields](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm71/fm7111.pdf)*. Fund. Math. 71 (1971), no. 1, 1–25.

It also appears as [Theorem 3.1](http://books.google.com/books?id=mUaeSDMASOMC&pg=PA45) in [Stable Groups](http://books.google.com/books?id=mUaeSDMASOMC) by Poizat.

Comment: @t.b. Thanks for adding the links. Brett: I should maybe point out that the theorem proven in these references is that totally transcendental implies algebraically closed. The remaining step that $\aleph_1$-categorical implies totally transcendental is part of the standard presentation of Morley's Theorem, which can be found in Marker or Hodges for example.

Comment: Thanks. I have a copy of Marker, so the last bit shouldn't be a problem.